# Select substring group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, substring

I have data in column which I want to `select` with `substring_index` and `group by` the result of substring. Is it possible to make in one query?:

Example

```
code:
R0001.10
R0001.20
R0002.10
R0002.30
```

If use

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(code, '.', 1) FROM products;
```

It goes like this:

```
R0001
R0001
R0002
R0002
```

But when I use

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(code, '.', 1) FROM products GROUP BY code;
```

It gave some strange result

```
01
01
010210000
0103020
```

etc.

Comment: Check my posted answer there is another issue in your query.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue using `GROUP BY` clause check [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86671/2). Might be other issue.